# Stats API Temporarily Down

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, cpp-ethereum

I deployed ethereum pool, i can connect and send valid share to  pool but always the page show Stats API Temporarily Down

my config.json

```
{
        "threads": 2,
        "coin": "eth",
        "name": "main",

        "proxy": {
                "enabled": true,
                "listen": "0.0.0.0:8888",
                "limitHeadersSize": 1024,
                "limitBodySize": 256,
                "behindReverseProxy": false,
                "blockRefreshInterval": "120ms",
                "stateUpdateInterval": "3s",
                "difficulty": 2000000000,
                "hashrateExpiration": "3h",

                "healthCheck": true,
                "maxFails": 100,

                "stratum": {
                        "enabled": true,
                "listen": "0.0.0.0:8008",
                        "timeout": "120s",
                        "maxConn": 8192
                },

                "policy": {
                        "workers": 8,
                        "resetInterval": "60m",
                        "refreshInterval": "1m",

                        "banning": {
                                "enabled": false,
                                "ipset": "blacklist",
                                "timeout": 1800,
                                "invalidPercent": 30,
                                "checkThreshold": 30,
                                "malformedLimit": 5
                        },
                        "limits": {
                                "enabled": false,
                                "limit": 30,
                                "grace": "5m",
                                "limitJump": 10
                        }
                }
        },

        "api": {
                "enabled": true,
                "purgeOnly": false,
                "purgeInterval": "10m",
                "listen": "127.0.0.1:8080",
                "statsCollectInterval": "5s",
                "hashrateWindow": "30m",
                "hashrateLargeWindow": "3h",
                "luckWindow": [64, 128, 256],
                "payments": 1,
                "blocks": 50
        },

        "upstreamCheckInterval": "5s",
        "upstream": [
                {
                        "name": "main",
                        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
                        "timeout": "10s"
                },
                {
                        "name": "backup",
                        "url": "http://127.0.0.2:8545",
                        "timeout": "10s"
                }
        ],

        "redis": {
                "endpoint": "127.0.0.1:6379",
                "poolSize": 10,
                "database": 0,
                "password": ""
        },

        "unlocker": {
                "enabled": false,
                "poolFee": 1.0,
                "poolFeeAddress": "",
                "donate": true,
                "depth": 120,
                "immatureDepth": 20,
                "keepTxFees": false,
                "interval": "10m",
                "daemon": "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
                "timeout": "10s"
        },

        "payouts": {
                "enabled": false,
                "requirePeers": 25,
                "interval": "120m",
                "daemon": "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
                "timeout": "10s",
                "address": "0x0",
                "gas": "21000",
                "gasPrice": "50000000000",
                "autoGas": true,
                "threshold": 50000000000,
                "bgsave": false
        },

        "newrelicEnabled": false,
        "newrelicName": "MyEtherProxy",
        "newrelicKey": "SECRET_KEY",
        "newrelicVerbose": false
}
```

what i can do? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `www/config/environment.js` file and set the `ApiUrl` value. See https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool for more details.  If you've already done this, ensure that your `ApiUrl` is reachable and set correctly. The URL should point to the server hosting the pool frontend server (or a proxy).

Comment: Thanks, after change  www/config/environment.js, we must ./build again